# Trouble with understanding params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand where is :post_id and :comment came from to 'create' action. There is no reference to them in from_for function. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html "7.4 Generating a Controller":

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for([@post, @post.comments.build])` will produce a form with the action of a url "create a comment for a post", this url has the `post_id`. And the `:comment` comes from the form element, which has name attribute like `name="comment[commenter]"`(which comes from :`<%= f.text_field :commenter %>`),`name="comment[body]"`(which comes from: `<%= f.text_area :body %>`) and so on.